# PHP TCP client listener

Tags: php, tcp, cron, tcpclient

I have a problem with php client.

What I can:

1) connect to tcp server using password

2) read string from tcp server

3) save xml string from tcp server to file once

4) close connect

What I want:

1) save xml string from tcp server to file in loop - about 10 seconds delay (never close)

Technical info:

I must read first header response from server, for example "Hello stranger".
Add my pass to string and send it to server.
I did it fluently.

TCP stream (XML file) from server ends char NULL (0x00)

My code:

```
<?php
$cfgPort    = "666";     //that's not my port, server and pass :-D           
$cfgTimeOut = "5";
$cfgServer ="myserver.pl";
$password = "donald";
$socket =fsockopen("$cfgServer",$cfgPort,$cfgTimeOut);
if (!$socket)
{
echo "Not conn\r\n";
}
else
{
echo "Conn!\r\n";
        $key = fread($socket, 81);
    //$key = fgets($socket, 82);

//what should I use fread or fgets ???

        $key_password = $key.$password;
// log in
        fwrite($socket, $key_password."\r\n");

//I checked response from server

        echo fread($socket, 18);

        //if authorized
        //body response 

        $his = fread($socket, 2048);
        $xml_clear = substr($his, 1, -1);
        $file = 'xml.xml';
        file_put_contents($file, $xml_clear);       
fclose($socket);
}
echo "The end!\r\n";
?>
```

Next question:

I must use a CRON to do that?

In telnet I can send header packet (password) once and I'm waiting to response for live. Can I do that in PHP?

Comment: It's really simple to do with CRON, in your cPanel, if you have any... just make the that code run every 10 minutes.

Comment: I know that, but I looking for help to not send the header (password) all the time.

Comment: All you want is to get a string from a URL and saving it in an XML file? If that's the case use cURL: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-sending-username-password/

Comment: In this step - yes.
I know it's a simple procedure but I falter in this place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use cURL to get the file and extract the string from it this way:

```css
pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  display: block;
  padding: 9.5px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
 }
```

```html
<pre>
<?php
 $username='donald';
 $password='donald';
 $url='http://odedta.com/projects/tests/test.php';

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
 $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
 $response=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 var_dump($result);
?>
</pre>
```

The result is the dumping of the xml content. Once you are done with all the modifications to the string/files you can use `file_put_contents()` and then run a CRON job to run that file every 10 minutes.

Here's the CRON command to run that file every 10 minutes:
`php -f /home/yourusername/public_html/path/to/project/test.php`

**Revision 1:**
If you want to get header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
```

**Revision 2:**
If you want to send information to your server you can use this example script:

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
$fields = array(
                        'lname' => urlencode($last_name),
                        'fname' => urlencode($first_name),
                        'title' => urlencode($title),
                        'company' => urlencode($institution),
                        'age' => urlencode($age),
                        'email' => urlencode($email),
                        'phone' => urlencode($phone)
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Where `$fields` is an array of variables or strings (in your case) that you want to send to the server.

As for adding your password to a string or whatnot, just use PHP concat, using dot, e.g.: `$password.$smystring`

Comment: Excellent! But, how abut "I must read first header response from server, for example "Hello stranger". Add my pass to string and send it to server."?

Comment: Please view my revised answer. If this answers your question, please accept it as an answer.